# Opencv - Shape detection from canny edge low res image

Tags: python, opencv, canny-operator

my goal is to detect basic geometric shape (square, triangle, prism, circle)from canny edges images.
This is a sample of my actual image data (triangle):

[image]

I've tried to add some transformation like Dilate/closing and then erode.

```
kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
dila = cv2.dilate(edges, kernel, iterations=1)
closed = cv2.morphologyEx(dila, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
eroded = cv2.erode(closed, kernel, iterations=2)
```

Dilate:

[image]

Closing:

[image]

And Erode:

[image]

Before passing it to this funtion, aimed to find total vertex to determine the shape:

```
def shape_detect(img):
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2:]
    x = 0
    y= 0
    shape = ''
    approx = ''
    for cnt in contours:
        area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        #approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.02*cv2.arcLength(cnt, True), True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.03*cv2.arcLength(cnt, True), True)
    return approx
```

Unfortunately it fails most of the time as contourns remain too fuzzy.
What could be a good transformation to apply? shall I use different approach?
many Thanks!