# Opencv - Detect contour sides

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, contour

I need to detect and approximate contour sides from this low res irregular triangle shapes.
From this one:

[image]

I need to detect the 3 sides in order to discriminate the shape is a triangle:

[image]

I tried with approxpolydp without success (approx vertex counting)

```
approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.04 * peri, True)
if len(approx) == 3:
            shape = "triangle"
```

Is it possible to approximate the countour with straight line and not fuzzy one?
thx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Opencv - Shape detection from canny edge low res image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64791287/opencv-shape-detection-from-canny-edge-low-res-image)